# Leer body de toda las response Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Necesito algún mecanismo para leer el body json de todas las respuestas a las peticiones HTTP que pasan por una aplicación desarrollada en Spring 3. He visto que para Spring 4 y 5 sí que hay wrappers como ContentCachingRequestWrapper que se escriben mientras se escribe en el servlet, pero en Spring 3 no he encontrado nada.

¿Existe algún mecanismo para poder leer todas las respuestas json que pasan por una aplicación con Java + Spring 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En todas las versiones de Spring tienes `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, que puedes extender para interceptar llamados HTTP.
Si sobreescribes el método:

`preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)`

puedes inspeccionar el parámetro request y allí encontrarás el json (o lo que busques).

Comment: Solamente permite leer 1 vez el outputStream del response parece. De ahí el uso de ContentCachingRequestWrapper como listener. Si intento acceder al wrapper del respons dice que ya se ha cerrado el flujo...

Comment: Ah perdona, quería decir leer la respuesta json del response

Comment: Ah, porque ContentCachingRequestWrapper es para el request. 
Pero el response lo arma tu aplicación, lo que quieres hacer es verificar que el json producido esté correcto, o algo así?

Comment: Sí, añadir una cabecera a todos mis json y luego un tema de logging también

Comment: Y con postHandle() en el HandlerInterceptorAdapter tampoco puedes?

Comment: Tampoco, da el mismo error. Dice que está el flujo cerrado.¿ No existe nada más en Java 6?